# Howto activate eclipse java warning "unnecessary declaration of thrown exception" without getting false positives?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

I hate functions that declare to throw exceptions that are not thrown by this functions in any case. This happens in refactorings if `throw` statements are removed in the function body without removing it from the `throws` definitions.

Thats why I activated the setting Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Unnecessary code -> Unnecessary declaration of thrown exception.

[image]

This leads to false positive warnings if exceptions are defined in interfaces or super methods. If implementation A of the interface does not throw one exception type, but implementation B does, eclipse warns about the unnecessary declaration in implemantation A. Thats equally for super and overriden methods. Thats why I activate the suboption "Ignore in overriding and implementing methods".

Perfeclty fine till here. But I have the oposite case. The overridden method throws a exception type, that is not used in the super method. See this minimal example:

```java
class Vehicle {
    protected int getStatus() throws GeneralException, StatusException {
        throw new GeneralException("One exception type in super type only");
    }
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    @Override
    protected int getStatus() throws GeneralException, StatusException {
        throw new StatusException("Special case, that gets special handling");
    }
}
```

Now StatusException in Vehicle is warned in eclipse.

[image]

Of course one could argue that this is bad design etc., but from a pragmatic point of view this will happen again and most probably one can accept to not change the architecture, but to simply add the new exception type to the super type. **But howto get rid of the false positive warning in this case?** Of course one could use the suboption with the javadoc, but this would also ignore most real positive hits. Another option is to add the SuppressWarning annotation "unused", but other users could get unneeded warnings for that suppression.

Comment: Well, some people argue that all exceptions should be unchecked exceptions...

Comment: This is a good point. I don't see any advantage of checked exceptions in my cases. But this is legacy code and I'm not sure whether it is an option to change everything to unchecked. But this could be the reason why there is no own suboption for it, because nobody uses checked exceptions anymore?

Comment: The plain English reading of "Ignore in overriding and implementing methods" is that *that* option should do what you want. Perhaps a bug in Eclipse?

Comment: @Raedwald Although I'm not a native speaker I don't think so. That's why I put all this explanation into the question, because this is a different situation from the point of view of the super type. And it also affects performance if you would need to scan for all implementations in the super type. So probably one need to start a feature request to manually deactivate the warning per exception type like `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` can do e.g. in function parameters. But this ain't a eclipse feature request, but a general java (compiler), right?

Answer (score 5):

Personally I'd activate the second option under the warning setting: "Ignore exceptions documented..." and just *document* those:

```
/**
 * @throws GeneralException when general stuff goes wrong
 * @throws StatusException when status stuff goes wrong
 */
protected int getStatus() throws GeneralException, StatusException {
    throw new GeneralException("One exception type in super type only");
}
```

*Maybe* include a slightly more useful explanation, but it'll basically boild down to this.

Comment: I mentioned that possible solution in the question myself and described why it is no solution for me. Nevertheless it is a possibility and I even will accept it, if I would know howto stop auto filling `@throws` in javadoc, i.e. if I enter `/**` before a function and hit enter all current possible javadoc tags are entered automatically. That's why this is documented everywhere mostly completly useless...